# Memory Consumption issue in the image generation from Video - AVAsset

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, cgimage, avasset

I want to create the `Photos` like video view , where in footer I there will be one one second's frame of video.

[image]

for that I am using this code

```
var imgs : [UIImage] = []
let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: video)
assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

let duration = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(video.duration))
    for i in 0 ... duration   {
        if let img = generateFrames(assetImgGenerate : assetImgGenerate , fromTime: Float64(i))
        {
            imgs.append(img)

        }
```

The code is working fine. I am getting the same result as I want.

Now the issue is - **If the video size is more then 50 seconds and I am extracting the uiimage then my app crashes as the memory goes beyond the free space of device.**

My videos are of 120 to 200 seconds. What can be better approach for this in terms of memory management. (I can not do lazy loading of the images as I want the images to be preloaded in the screen.)

**EDIT**

```
 func generateFrames(assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator,   fromTime:Float64) -> UIImage? {

    let time : CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 1)
    var img: CGImage?

  img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at:time, actualTime: nil)

}
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that the images that are generated are of really high quality and take up huge lump of space on memory. I would recommend to use low/thumbnail quality image for preview (In the screenshot above).

Comment: Besides the size of your thumbnail frames you should be using also an autoreleasepool closure inside your for loop

Comment: Btw you can get a Double from your duration accessing the seconds property. `video.duration.seconds`

Comment: Provide the definition of `generateFrames` method. Also what is the size of generated image?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Please check my edited question. And my videos are of both vertical and horizontal. So can not be sure of size.

Comment: @ CoderFrom94 I have tried to scale up my uiimage to 0.5 - 0.1. but that approach was not helpful. but I can try with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to reduce its quality.

Comment: @LeoDabus , I want to keep my image object. Won't autoreleasepool will release my image?

Comment: @Bindi updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to specify the [`maximumSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetimagegenerator/1387560-maximumsize) of the thumbnail image. e.g.

```
let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: video)
assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
// Here specify the size in which you want to fit the image.
assetImgGenerate.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

It's the array of images that is consuming lot of memory if the image size is large.